# Google Play In - App Billing : License Key Change Issue

Tags: android

I am in middle of developing a new app which uses In - App billing feature.

During testing, I experienced that license key of my app which is used to
connect app to Google play servers for billing got changed when some
profile information on Developer console for my app was changed.

Does anyone know, what are the events which trigger a change in license key of
the app?